# How to get indices of a specific value in a tensor in tensorflow-js?

Tags: tensorflow.js

For example, If I have a 2D tensor of `[[1,3],[2,1]]`, how can I get indices of the value `1`? (It should return `[[0,0],[1,1]]`).

I took a look into `tf.where` but the API is complicated and I don't think that would solve the problem for me

Comment: Does my answer solve it?

Comment: absolutely thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using [tf.whereAsync](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#whereAsync).

Just create a mask which checks if the values in the input Tensor are of the value 1 and turn them into boolean values.

**Mask:**

```
"Tensor
    [[true , false],
     [false, true ]]"
```

`tf.whereAsync()` returns the coordinates of true elements of the condition which in this case come from the mask.

```
(async function getData() {
  const x = tf.tensor2d([[1, 3], [2, 1]])

  const mask = x.equal([1]).asType('bool');
  const coords = await tf.whereAsync(mask);
  coords.print();
}());
```

**Input:**

```
"Tensor
    [[1, 3],
     [2, 1]]"
```

**Output:**

```
"Tensor
    [[0, 0],
     [1, 1]]"
```